# Openpyxl how to parse SUBTOTAL formula to excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to input the subtotal formula to excel spreadsheet with the following:

```
ws['I10'] = "=SUBTOTAL(9;I{0}:I{1})".format(1,9))
```

I get the following warning:

[image]

If i try to do a simple summation it works.
Is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Yes, you must use commas to separate parameters in formulae.

Comment: Wow amazing!! Thanks alot!!

Comment: This is covered in the openpyxl docs. I blame Microsoft's overenthusiastic adoption of localisation in its products, including translation of functions, etc.